# how can i collapse all folder with alt+click on sublime text 3 (boxy theme)

Tags: sublimetext3, ubuntu-16.04, boxy

I am using Sublime Text 3 with boxy theme. But i can not collapse all folder with alt + click. When i use default theme it is working. Is there any setting for this problem?

OS: Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: could be an odd Sublime Text on Linux bug - it works fine in Windows with the Default theme and with Boxy. I can't see anything in Boxy (or the Default theme) that seems to refer to mouse modifier keys.

Comment: thanks i found solution for it, remove theme :)